# django unit test for delele api is failing due to csrf cookie not set

Tags: django, unit-testing, cookies, django-rest-framework

I have written a unit test for `delete` REST API and its failing on

```
{u'detail': u'CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set.'}
```

Not sure why its checking CSRF cookie, though I have set `enforce_csrf_checks=True` in top of the test case.

Here is my test case

```
def setUp(self):
    self.user = Customer.objects.create_user(email="test@gmail.com", password="12345678open", username="tanvir")
    self.requirement_header = RequirementHeader.objects.create_requirement_header(user=self.user)
    self.requirement_header_id = self.requirement_header.id
    self.description = "Description"
    self.file = '/requirements/test_data/test.txt'
    self.requirement_lines = RequirementLine.objects.get_or_create(
        requirement_header=self.requirement_header,
        description=self.description,
        file=self.file,
    )[0]

def test_delete_requirement_line(self):
    client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=True)
    logged_in = client.login(username=self.user.email, password='12345678open')
    if logged_in:
        data = {
            'deleting_user': self.user.email
        }
        response = client.delete('/api/requirements/requirement-line/%d/' % self.requirement_lines.id, data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 204)
```

In fact, here `response.data` returns `{u'detail': u'CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set.'}` and that's why the status code is `303` and test is failing.

My API View:

```
class RequirementLineRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView(BaseRetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    serializer_class = RequirementLineSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def delete(self, request, requirement_line_id, *args, **kwargs):
        deleting_user = request.user
        try:
            obj = RequirementService().delete_requirement_line(
                deleting_user=deleting_user,
                requirement_line_id=requirement_line_id,
            )
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
            return Response(e.message, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I am using Django 1.9 and DRF 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `enforce_csrf_checks=True` then you are telling Django to actually *do* a CSRF test. What you likely want to do is *not* do CSRF checking during tests.

> [Forcing CSRF validation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/) - By default, requests created with APIRequestFactory will not have CSRF validation applied when passed to a REST framework view. If you need to explicitly turn CSRF validation on, you can do so by setting the enforce_csrf_checks flag when instantiating the factory.

So, simply delete the `enforce_csrf_checks=True` as the default is `enforce_csrf_checks=False`.

Comment: ok,one question,just an additional one, is it okay if i write unit test without having csrf checks?

Comment: The csrf checks are automatically disabled during tests, so I'd say its okay not to write tests for them. And Django's csrf protection code itself is tested by Django's own tests.